# Shareplum module not found when running python script via powershell in SQL server agent

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, shareplum

I have a python script which works in python using the shareplum module to access and move files to SharePoint from a local folder location.

I then run into a problem executing this via SQL Server Agent using a step which is run as an administrator with the relevant access and is type "Powershell".

I have other python scripts executed in this way without issue.

The error is as follows...

The error information returned by PowerShell is: '  File "PYTHON FILE LOCATION AND FILENAME", line 1, in       from shareplum import Site  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shareplum'    '.  Process Exit Code 0.  The step succeeded.

Appreciate any insight.

Thanks

Will

Comment: perhaps you used pip to install the shareplum module into a user specific folder, which isn't the same user that sql agent runs under

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siggermannen was right...

The pip installer had been saved to a specific user folder.